# Horizantal Recycler view is loading too many elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recycler view inside of a vertical recycler view.  Think of it as a slideshow inside a feed of content views.  When the content view with the slideshow loads, it seems to load all 25 views rather than just the ones that are visible on screen.  What I want to be able to do is set a limit on how many elements are loaded that are not currently visible.  Is this possible with nested horizontal inside a vertical recyclerview?

Comment: is this a Nolan movie? XD

Comment: sorry if complicated, im really just trying to set limit of views shown in a nested recycler view